# C language definition of this variable means

Tags: c

```
const u_int16  myDeviceDescriptor [] = "\p"
"\x12" // Length
 "\x01" // Type (Device Descriptor)
```

what it means, \x12 or \p

Comment: @KVD yeah right. Google for what, "\p"?

Comment: These are "escape sequences", a way to express special characters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: This does not look like initialization defined by the C standard (unless, in the C implementation being used, `u_int16` is a character type). It may be an extension, or it may be invalid code.

Comment: Not 100% sure because the syntax is kinda wonky, but it seems to want to be an array...so it means \x12 AND \p...just in different positions...

Comment: Where does `u_int16` come from?

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippets seems to be part of an implementation of the USB protocol. The `uint_16` array is written as the concatenation of several small strings to ease readability. Each hexadecimal value is followed by its meaning written as a comment.

The `\p` is to indicate a '[Pascal string](http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/~jordan/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Pascal-Strings.html)'. It is a rather old construct, not available on all compilers. It requires the `-fpascal-strings`.

Comment: Humm, nice to know about `\p`. Good answer, +1 for the Pascal string detail. gcc doesn't seem to support it though.

Comment: It used to, but the `-fpascal-strings` flag has been deprecated. The Intel compiler [still allows it](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/460392).

Answer (score 1):

In standard C, "\x12" means a string containing a character with value 18 (hexadecimal 12<sub>16</sub>), and "\x01" is a string containing a character with value 1. `"\p"` is not a standard C escape sequence, but it could be an extension.

In standard C, three successive strings like this are concatenated into one string (and terminated by a null character). The resulting string can be used to initialize a character array (an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`).

`myDeviceDescriptor` is declared as an array of `u_int16`. Unless `u_int16` is an alias (via `typedef`) for `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, then initializing `myDeviceDescriptor` with this string is not defined by the C standard. Although it is possible that `u_int16` is such an alias, it is unlikely unless this code was written for a special environment with 16-bit bytes.

It is possible that this syntax is an extension specific to the C implementation it was designed for, an extension that allows initializing arrays of `u_int16` with string literals.

You would need documentation for the C implementation or other specific information about this code to determine what `"\p"` is and whether this extension is supported.

Another possibility is that the code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing a compile time string concatenation. When you write something like:

```
"hello" " world" "\n"
```

It is equivalent to

```
"hello world\n"
```

Thus, the string you have in this code is `"\p\x12\x01"`.

However, I believe this is invalid code: there is no such thing as `\p` in standard C. It can be an extension, but it's not defined by the standard. `\xhh` is valid for hexadecimal representation. But keep in mind that you're assigning a pointer to a characters sequence (more specifically, a pointer to a constant string initializer) to a `u_int16` array, which is really an odd thing to do. Unless this code is targeted to a specific platform, or you're working on some embedded system or something like that, you have to be careful with it.